# Download File From Dropbox Without Using API

Tags: php, dropbox

My problem is simple. I want to download a Dropbox file via PHP to my server. Sample Dropbox URL (not actual URL):

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/tnrRxOCfzR4hN70jpWfIpZelnPqCLjPJQ3Ii0S1tDQ3RIgcCVCTphsAzAEiis309?dl=1
```

When I personally download it, of course it works.

But when I try to use `curl` or `file_get_contents`, it doesn't work. I know my `curl` code works since I can download other files from other sites using the same code. So there must be something I missed to download something from Dropbox.

I want to download the file without using the Dropbox API.

Anyone?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is my cUrl code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/SAMPLELINKONLYtDQ3RIgcCVCTphsAzAEiis309?dl=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookiejar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    $this->output = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $header_size = $this->info['header_size'];
    $this->head = substr($this->output, 0, $header_size);
    $this->body = substr($this->output, $header_size);

    curl_close($ch);
```

After which I get the body and save it into an image file:

```
    file_put_contents($this->download_folder.'/image-' . time() . rand(1000, 9999) . '.jpg', $this->body);
```

The `file_put_contents` code is done similarly:

```
    file_put_contents($this->download_folder.'/image-' . time() . rand(1000, 9999) . '.jpg', file_get_contents(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/SAMPLELINKONLYtDQ3RIgcCVCTphsAzAEiis309?dl=1));
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: including what @Hassan said, can you show what you tried with `curl` and `file_get_contents` including all `CURLOPT_*` settings you pass to curl.

Comment: Reiterating what the above commenters have said already, please include what you've already tried. One thing that may be relevant though, is that if you're using a Dropbox shared link (e.g., it contains "/s/") you should use that link itself, (modified as necessary: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 ) and not the resulting /content_link/. Make sure you have curl follow redirects though.

Comment: Added sample code above.

Comment: @Greg: I actually got that link above (although modified) from cUrl following the redirects. It was originally a bit.ly link which cUrl followed to that final link.

Comment: Try changing `dl=1` to `raw=1` in the URL

Comment: @Phil: Okay will try now.

Comment: @Phil: Didn't work :(

Comment: URLs with dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link have certain access control behaviors, so you shouldn't use them directly. What are the intermediary links? You should use a /s/ version.

Comment: Solved the problem. Your comments definitely pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: First problem was cUrl was timing out. Next the script itself was timing out.

Comment: @Greg: You're right. I should use the right URL. That was a huge hint for me to get this solved.

Comment: How did you solve this. Please share it. I am also want to do this